# how to block cycle on many elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have this kind of jquery cycle handling 2 elements (#rotator1, #rotator2) :

```
    $("#rotator1, #rotator2").cycle(
        {
            fx: 'fade',
            sync: 1,
            speed: 800,
            prev: '#headerButtonBack',
            next: '#headerButtonNext',                
            timeout: 4000,
            pause: 1
        }
    );
```

and I'd like, when a user is on #rotator1 with mouse (mouseover), block also the cycle of the #rotator2.

Is it possible? How? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give both slideshow a certain class (i used pics);

On hover you can do something like:

```
$('#rotator1, #rotator2').hover(function() {
    $('.pics').cycle('pause'); return false;
}, function() {
    $('.pics').cycle('resume'); return false;
 });
```

There is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/psxgT/1/

Comment: on hover of one of the slideshows you set the cycle-plugin on paused, when your mouse moves out it will resume. No overriding you giving some arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html)?

Here it is mentioned that when you will set the value of **pause to 1** then it will enable "pause on hover"

If some functionality is offered by default, you should not write your own code.

Best.

Comment: ??? I know pause is on hover, but I will aplly it on each element in the same moment! :)